# Managing (ordering) chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to order chrome extensions other than the limited functionality provided in the UI? The problem is that in the UI you can't order items in the drop down list/overflow area. I've looked at writing an extension but the `management.ExtensionInfo` object returned through the `chrome.management` apis doesn't contain the position. Editing `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` which does have the location doesn't work either.

Comment: Check out comments for this issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68414 .